# How to pass GeoIP HTTP request headers to backend with Apache?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, docker, http-headers, piwik

I am using nginx to proxy HTTP requests to a PHP application running in the scope of Apache 2.4 (mod_php5) within a Docker container ([cbeer/piwik](https://hub.docker.com/r/cbeer/piwik/)).

```
                     +------------------------------+
                     |        Docker Container      |
+-------+            |  +--------+          +-----+ |
| nginx |----------->|->| apache |--------->| php | |
+-------+ proxy_pass |  +--------+ mod_php5 +-----+ |
                     +------------------------------+
```

The PHP application is Piwik 2.16.

I inject GeoIP HTTP headers with nginx:

```
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Addr             "$remote_addr";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Country-Code     "$geoip_country_code";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Country-Name     "$geoip_country_name";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Continent-Code   "$geoip_city_continent_code";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Region-Name      "$geoip_region_name";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Region           "$geoip_region";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-City             "$geoip_city";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Metro-Code       "$geoip_dma_code";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Area-Code        "$geoip_area_code";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Latitude         "$geoip_latitude";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Longitude        "$geoip_longitude";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Postal-Code      "$geoip_postal_code";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Isp              "$geoip_org";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Organization     "$geoip_org";
proxy_set_header GeoIP-Netspeed         "";
```

Unfortunately Piwik (at least thinks it) cannot see the via nginx injected request HTTP headers. On the Piwik settings page for geolocationing is a warning about Piwik could not find GeoIP variables within PHP's `$_SERVER`. The GeoIP headers arrive as e.g. `HTTP_GEOIP_ADDR` but have to be `GEOIP_ADDR`. I also cannot edit the application to get use of these "new" header names.

@RichardSmith mentioned that I have to map `HTTP_GEOIP_` variables to `GEOIP_` within Apache using setenv. I tried several combinations but I did not get managed to use variables (request headers) as values for the environment variable.

```
SetEnv GEOIP_ADDR "%{HTTP_GEOIP_ADDR}e"
```

This results into the actual string "`%{HTTP_GEOIP_CITY}e`" stored in the variable instead of the value of `HTTP_GEOIP_CITY`.

How to map `HTTP_GEOIP_` variables to `GEOIP_` within Apache using setenv?

Comment: I would really not assume, that apache by itself removes any header automatically. Are you sure, that your application is expecting the header in the same format you're providing it, eg. `$_SERVER["HTTP_GEOIP_REGION"]` By the way, check with phpinfo() to make sure that PHP really can not see the HTTP_GEOIP_* headers. I suspect that this is not the issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to map `HTTP_GEOIP_` variables to `GEOIP_` within Apache using [setenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612228/setting-a-php-server-value-serversomething-using-apache-htaccess)

Comment: @burnersk should that be a `$` rather than a `%`. I haven't used Apache for a while, so if you get a working solution, post it as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that the variables are really `set` in Nginx `.conf`?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they wouldn't be on on the Apache side with "wrong" header names, right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption on Apache's `SetEnv` directive syntax is wrong.

From the documentation, it seems it's the other way around:

`SetEnv HTTP_GEOIP_ADDR %{GeoIP-Addr}e`

Here is the link for the documentation:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

It states that `Sets an internal environment variable, which is then available to Apache HTTP Server modules, and passed on to CGI scripts and SSI pages.`

```
Example

SetEnv SPECIAL_PATH /foo/bin
```

So, if you swap your declaration, might work.